NextAuth.js Subdomain Cookie Issue: Cookies Inaccessible on Subdomains
I'm working on implementing authentication using AuthJS (NextAuth) in a Next.js app. I want the session and CSRF cookies to be accessible across subdomains (e.g., *.localhost:3000) as well as the main domain (localhost:3000).
I configured the cookies like this in authOptions:
cookies: {
  sessionToken: {
    name: "next-auth.session-token",
    options: {
      domain: process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_COOKIE_DOMAIN || ".alchmy.com", // Set cookie for all subdomains
      httpOnly: true,
      secure: process.env.NODE_ENV === "production",
      sameSite: "lax",
      path: "/",
    },
  },
  csrfToken: {
    name: "next-auth.csrf-token",
    options: {
      domain: process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_COOKIE_DOMAIN || ".alchmy.com",
      httpOnly: false,
      secure: process.env.NODE_ENV === "production",
      sameSite: "lax",
      path: "/",
    },
  },
}

My .env is set like this:
NEXT_PUBLIC_COOKIE_DOMAIN=.localhost

The issue is that cookies are attaching correctly to localhost:3000, but they are inaccessible when I try to access any subdomain like subdomain.localhost:3000. The browser is not sending the cookies in requests to the subdomains.
I configured the domain for both sessionToken and csrfToken cookies to be .localhost in the environment file. I expected this to allow the cookies to be shared across all subdomains, but this isn't working as intended.
I also tried various cookie options like changing sameSite, but I keep getting MissingCSRF errors on the login page after login.
How can I make the cookies accessible on subdomains when using NextAuth?
